# Shell script -path and run command in one line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to execute "n" number of shell script using a master shell script (which have all the command to start other shell script). Since all other shell script are located in different location,can't give same path for all and I don't want to repeat "cd" command will be repeating for doing the same.

Apart from this, is there any way that i can start my shell script with both run and path given in one line?

eg:

```
"run command" "path" (for  file)
"run command" "path" (for  file1)
```

Kindly can anyone help on this.

Comment: You'd better show some code so we can better understand the problem. You can for example use `DEFAULT_PATH="/your/path"` and then call scripts with `$DEFAULT_PATH/script1.sh`, `$DEFAULT_PATH/script2.sh`, etc.

Comment: Is it not possible to use an absolute path to the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am able to understand your requirement, it lists down following objectives:

1. You dont want to change your current path in order to execute different scripts at different paths.

   Solution:

   a. You can directly run your scripts in command line with full absolute path without changing your current path.

   b. You can use bash commands, pushd and popd to frequently switch between your current path and the other location.
2. Starting the shell script with both run and path given in one line.
   Solution:

   This can be achieved by use of semi colon between the two commands. For example:
   Creating a folder in some other location than current directory through 1 line command can be done as:

   `cd /home/user ; mkdir testfolder`
3. If the run command uses path as an input argument to run command.
   Solution:

   This can be achieved by using pushd and popd commands before execution of each command.

Comment: Or for 3, you can run in a subshell.  `( cd "$path"; "$cmd" )` will not change the working directory of the parent shell (the parentheses forces the commands to be executed in their own subshell).

Comment: But running in separate shall give one limitation that the any temporary variables/Lables that are being set (or being export) in one script will not be recognized in the other.

Comment: if I use one line ./shell1.sh ; d:/newfolder/sample1 ..its working fine..but for second line again  i have to use "cd .." for two times for coming back to "d" drive... then I can give next line as ./shell2.sh; d:/newfolder/sample2 ... here how can i avoid "cd .." (which used twice)...

Comment: If you have paths like `d:/` you are not on Linux.